# Scala adding immutable list to mutable one

Tags: list, scala, immutability, mutable, prepend

I am trying to add some user input `String`s to an immutable `List` with tail recursion and then add this immutable `List` to a `MutableList` which is defined.
Somehow this immutable `List` isn't getting prepended to my `MutableList`. Why is that so?

EDIT: Updated the code. Now its working!

```
val list = scala.collection.mutable.MutableList[String]()

  def exerciseSelector() {
    val user = scala.io.StdIn.readLine("go:")
    user match {
      case "add" => val tempList = scanInput(List[String]())
                    if (!tempList.isEmpty) list ++= tempList.get ; exerciseSelector()
      case "print" => println(list)
      case "exit" => sys.exit()
    }
  }

    def scanInput(acc: List[String]): Option[List[String]] = {
    val input = scala.io.StdIn.readLine("User input:")
    input match {
    case "stop" => Option(acc)
    case input: String => scanInput(input :: acc)
  }
}

exerciseSelector()
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have two mutually-recursive functions `exerciseSelector` and `scanInput`, which will only ever result in list being updated if `scanInput` returns, which ultimately can only happen after an input of "exit", which calls `sys.exit()`, quitting altogether before the return from `scanInput` can happen, and so before `list` ever gets updated.

Any input of "print" will be printing out an empty list, as list never gets a chance to be updated without `sys.exit()` being called first.

Depending on what exactly you are trying to achieve, I suspect just dropping out the co-recursive call to `exerciseSelector()` on receiving a "stop" input will fix your code (or get you a lot further towards your intended result).

Comment: Thank you very much now its working just fine!!

So let me just summarize this up again: If i remove the exerciseSelector() call at the "stop" match case then the list can be returned, else the list isnt even returned and I am leaving the list behind in the scanInput() because i first called the exerciseSelector() and then returned the list???

Comment: @ArmaGeddon You are "leaving the list behind", as you put it, in scanList, because the call to `exerciseSelector()` in front of the to-be-returned `Option(acc)` will inevitably result in a call to `sys.exit()` - ending the program - before completing. Also, you probably shouldn't edit your question so that the code now works, or people reading it may not understand what the problem was nor how the solution fixed it (at least, not without looking at the history of edits).

Comment: Okay, so I missunderstood the behaviour of the case here becuase I thought even when I am calling the `exerciseSelector()` and returning the list back it will do both things but now its clear to me thanks!
Yes I edited it but last time another user told me not to "answer my question" or did he meant only not to do that if I am having further questions?

Comment: @ArmaGeddon I'm not sure what (s)he might have meant.

Comment: Never mind... For the next time, I will do it by just posting another answer than editing my question. Thank you for your help!